# zend 2 event manager wildcard + keywords

Tags: php, logging, controller, event-handling, zend-framework2

I'm currently working on a simple way to catch all my controllers actions.
As the Zend 2 documentation specify, you can use the '*' wildcard to listen on multiple events.

Each controller triggers the Event Manager when an important action is done (like a createAction, deleteAction, etc) but I'm unable to catch it... I'm trying this way:

```
$sharedEventManager->attach('*\Controller\*', '*', function ($e) {});
```

I think the wildcard can't be used with keywords and only works alone but it would catch all events instead of my controller's events...

Any help ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [glob pattern](http://php.net/glob) you use here is not possible with the Zend Framework 2 event manager. You have two options in using identifiers for the shared event manager:

1. Use the exact specified identifier for the event manager
2. Use the wildcard `*` to trigger on all events

There are, however, other options. You might already know, an event manager can have multiple identifiers. All controllers extending the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController` [have five identifiers registered](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/ca59a6cc26b5289f258e90880cf20649d8335450/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php#L163-L167):

1. `Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface`
2. `__CLASS` (thus, `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController`)
3. `get_class($this)` (thus, e.g. `MyModule\Controller\FooBarController`
4. `$this->eventIdentifier` (thus, anything you set yourself in this property)
5. `substr(get_class($this), 0, strpos(get_class($this), '\\'))` (thus, e.g. `MyModule`)

This is true for both the abstract action controller as well as the abstract restful controller.

So to listen to all controllers in a **single** module, use `MyModule` as identifier. Then check if the target implements the `DispatchableInterface`.

To listen to all controllers in **all** modules, use either `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController` or `Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface`. As far as I understand your question, you are looking for one of these identifiers.

NB. Realize that always another target could trigger an event inside an event manager. Thus, if you depend on the controller by using `$controller = $e->getTarget()`, always check if this target is an instance of a DispatchableInterface!